# Declarative Transactions in Node.js

Tags: java, node.js

Back in the day, it was common to manage database transactions in Java by writing code that did it. Something like this:

```
Transaction tx = session.startTransaction();
...
try {
   tx.commit();
} catch (SomeException e){
   tx.rollback();
}
```

at the beginning and end of every method. This had some obvious problems - it's redundant, hides the intent of what's happening, etc. So, along came annotation-driven transactions:

```
@Transaction
public SomeResultObj getResult(...){

    ...
}
```

Is there any support for declarative transaction management in node.js?

Comment: didn't know that was ever common... I've always written code to have a central place to execute JDBC code from and handle transactions, it's just a good idea...

Comment: Most people have avoided writing their own database transaction API because they dislike re-inventing the wheel, combined with the fact that most of the available options are safer, and easier to use than rolling your own.

Comment: Agreed with not rolling one's own database transaction API! I would certainly like to know if there are any existing declarative database transaction APIs in Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're using Express + Sequelize, you can do this by using a module called [`continuation-local-storage`](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage) (henceforth `cls`, for brevity).

### Show me the code

```
// When initializing your Sequelize instance
var Sequelize = require( "sequelize" );
Sequelize.cls = require( "continuation-local-storage" ).createNamespace( "db" );

module.exports = new Sequelize(...);
```

Then, create some middleware to initialize your transaction in every request (in case no one has come up with one yet):

```
var sequelize = require(...);
app.use(function ( req, res, next ) {
  sequelize.transaction(function () {
    // Do something else, but be sure to invoke next middleware
    next();    
  });
});
```

### What's going on here?

1. A `cls` namespace is declared for Sequelize to use. Must be set on the constructor;
2. A transaction is initialized in an Express middleware;
3. Every subsequent sequelize query *will* use the request transaction by default (you can override this behavior, obviously).

### How this works?

This works because `cls` assigns a new storage for each new async chain (the request in this example), and they are passed down consistently and transparently.
It's some kind of magic that happens inside Node :)

### Tips

It's very likely that you'll need to use some monkeypatch to take that approach. Depends on your Promises implementation.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-bluebird
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-q

### Further info

[Check the Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/transactions/#automatically-pass-transactions-to-all-queries).